# '7 days ago' date format issue in crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I am running a cron which includes a curl whch includes values for startDate and endDate which must be in the format yyyy-mm-dd. endDate is today and startDate is 7 days ago. Overall format is:

```
curl -o ~/location/filename.xml "http://url.asmx/do_this?&startDate=x&endDate=y"
```

Using a fixed start date this works running via terminal on macosx:

```
&startDate=2014-10-01&endDate=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`"
```

However, remembering that startDate should be 7 days prior to the system date, both of the methods below result in an error 'The specified Date was not in correct format. Dates should be in format: YYYY-MM-DD, such as 2011-12-24'

```
startDate=`date -d '7 days ago' +\%Y-\%m-\%d`&endDate=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
startDate=`date --date="7 days ago"  +\%Y-\%m-\%d`&endDate=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
```

Is this an issue with using " ' and `?

What am I doing wrong here? BTW I am trying to keep within a one line command line rather than use a script in a file.

EDIT: From Googling and copying and pasting many suggestions, I have found that the following on a Mac forum that works:

```
$(date -v-7d +%Y-%m-%d)
```

However I've not come across -v before. I'm wondering what it is, is it Mac specific and will this present problems on other servers?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an issue with using " ' and `?

Probably. Replacing `` with $() your command works:

```
curl -o ~/location/filename.xml "http://url.asmx/do_this?&startDate=$(date -d '7 days ago' +\%Y-\%m-\%d)&endDate=$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)"
```

Comment: Not working I'm afraid. I'm now running a bash script file using variables for the date values but same problem.

Comment: Works for me, however as you're using a script now, Can you please update your post with that script?

Answer (score 1):

The unquoted `&` is a command terminator. It will put the startDate variable definition in the background (a subshell) so it won't exist in the current shell. Demo:

```
$ startDate=`date -d '7 days ago' +\%Y-\%m-\%d`&endDate=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
[1] 25595
[1]+  Done                    startDate=`date -d '7 days ago' +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
$ echo $startDate--$endDate
--2014-10-14
```

Some `date`s recognize `+%F` as a short-hand for `+%Y-%m-%d`

Also, you have to be careful using `date` in a crontab entry: the `%` character will be translated into a newline unless escaped. Read your `crontab(5)` man page.

Comment: There are actually other variables in the URL:"url.asmx/do_this?&variable1=a&variable2=b&startDate=x&endDate=y". So I'm unclear why does the & affect the start date variable but not the preceding ones?